# Permanently filter properties/methods from intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Is there a local setting to Visual Studio to permanently filter items from intellisense?

In the Unity game engine, your components need to derive from MonoBehaviour which comes with a lot of junk:

[image: intellisense]

75% of those 80+ entries are marked deprecated and the other 24% you don't want to really use either.

I know about `EditorBrowsable` attribute but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your feedback and AFAIK, there is nu such setting to meet the requirement, please go to Help-Send Feedback-Suggest a feature to file this suggestion to the VS product Team, add the link in here and we will help you vote it, thanks for your understanding.